# Alert and mouse & key events

Tags: actionscript-3, air, actionscript-2

When showing an alert box with *mx.controls.Alert.show()* and clicking it's buttons with the mouse (or Enter key) or clicking anywhere, these events are passed to the parent window as well, eventually triggering buttons there etc.

Is there a straight forward way to prevent this, like setting an attribute of the alert instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `closeHandler` parameter in [show()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html#show%28%29) you can then call [event.stopPropagation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation%28%29) to prevent the event from being processed on subsequent nodes.

Code would look something like this:

```
Alert.show("Message", "Title", Alert.OK, parent, onClose);

function onClose(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Do close stuff here
}
```

### Edit

Added example for Flex 4.6, in Flash Builder 4.6:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private function onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
            {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAppClick);
                showAlert();
            }

            private function showAlert():void
            {
                Alert.show("An Alert", "Alert Title", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, this, onAlertClose);
            }

            private function onAlertClose(e:CloseEvent):void
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                trace("Alert Close");
            }

            private function onAppClick(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("App Click");
            }

            private function onBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("Button Click");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>

        <s:VerticalLayout
            gap="12"/>

    </s:layout>

    <s:Button
        label="A Clickable Button"
        click="onBtnClick(event)"/>

    <s:Button
        label="Show Alert"
        click="showAlert()"/>


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would only solve half of the problem as it doesn't prevent the application from reacting to your mouse clicks, when you click next to the alert box, not the alert box (buttons) itself.

Comment: Which version of Flex/Flash Builder are you using? I've added a sample app and I've not getting clicks on the buttons or the app when the Alert is up.